# Laravel Query Builder returning all rows despite 'where' statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a search service using the following blog post:https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db

This seems to work except for the fact that my queries are returning **every** row in the table rather than specific ones.

For example, I have a filter such as this:

```php
 public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value)
    {
        return $builder->whereHas('items', function ($q) use ($value) {
            $q->where('item_id', $value);
        });
    }
```

This works on the `items` relationship on my model. Running this query conventionally seems to work, but it fails in relation to the code in the above blog post.

The same is true for an even simpler query:

```php
public static function apply(Builder $builder, $value)
    {
        return $builder->where('name', $value);
    }
```

When I run my test it just gives me every single item in the table rather than those matching my condition.

My search code looks like this and I can't see any obvious errors:

```php
 public static function search(Request $filters)
    {
        $query =
            static::applyDecoratorsFromRequest(
                $filters,
                (new User)->newQuery()
            );

        return static::getResults($query);
    }

    private static function applyDecoratorsFromRequest(Request $request, Builder $query)
    {
        foreach ($request->all() as $filterName => $value) {

            $decorator = static::createFilterDecorator($filterName);

            if (static::isValidDecorator($decorator)) {
                $query = $decorator::apply($query, $value);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you should use local scopes instead : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes

```
public static function scopeWhereItem(Builder $query, $value)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('items', function (query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('item_id', $value);
        });
    }
```

Then in your controller :

```
// Initiate the queryBuilder
$query = YourModel::query();

// your request is like : ['item' => '2'];

foreach($request->all()sas $filterName => $value) {

    // Build the scope Name (whereItem())
    $scope_name = 'where' . ucFirst($filterName);

    $query->$scopeName($value);

}

$results = $query->get();
```

you can add some checks if the method `'scope' . ucFirst($scopeName)`  exists if you want

it will generate a query like this : `YourModel::query()->whereItem(2)->get()'`